# Check for each value in column has only one corresponding value in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have my data in pandas data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1234, 1234, 1234, 5678, 5678, 5678, 9999, 9999, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234],
 'Name': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'DD', 'EE', 'EE', 'CC', 'CC', 'BB', 'BB'])
```

```
      ID Name
0   1234   AA
1   1234   AA
2   1234   AA
3   5678   BB
4   5678   BB
5   5678   DD
6   9999   EE
7   9999   EE
8   1234   CC
9   1234   CC
10  1234   BB
11  1234   BB
```

I would like to add another field in this dataframe(with True/False) such that. for each id value, there should be only one corresponding values.

So, my expected output looks like this.. 
for the id - 1234 there are two corresponding values (AA and BB), the one with lesser count should be flagged.

```
      ID Name
5   5678   DD
8   1234   CC
9   1234   CC
10  1234   BB
11  1234   BB
```

Comment: `df.duplicates('NAME', keep=False)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang if there is another entry (1234,'BB') how could we also flag that. 
as (1234,'AA') has count 4, (1234,'BB') has count 2

Comment: `df.duplicates(['ID','NAME'], keep=False)`

Comment: the output for the above statement-
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True

wanted 5,6 to be flagged. :(

Comment: don't `5 True 6 True` mean that they are flagged already?

Comment: the values ```0 True 1 True 2 True 3``` True are also getting flagged. dont want this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208439/discussion-between-inderjeet-singh-and-quang-hoang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1234, 1234, 1234, 5678, 5678, 5678, 9999, 9999, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234],
 'Name': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'DD', 'EE', 'EE', 'CC', 'CC', 'BB', 'BB']}
)

# filter those ID's that appear with multiple names
non_unique = df.groupby('ID').Name.transform('nunique').ne(1)
df = df[non_unique]

# count the occurrences of each combination ['ID','Name']
counts = df[non_unique].groupby(['ID','Name']).Name.transform('count')

# filter those with minimal occurrences within each ID
df[counts == counts.groupby(df['ID']).transform('min')]
```

Output:

```
      ID Name
5   5678   DD
8   1234   CC
9   1234   CC
10  1234   BB
11  1234   BB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1234','1234','1234','1234','4567','1234'],'NAME':['AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','BB']})
df['CHECK'] = df.duplicated('ID', keep='last')
```

Comment: You only want to be flaged based on NAME column or both columns ?